# Bootstrap style design to table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

Here I have a datatable http://jsbin.com/aMAQUWe/1/edit

CODE:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
      function drawTable() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
        data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
          ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
          ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
          ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true]
        ]);

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='table_div'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to add twitter bootstrap design to this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the [Tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) documentation in Bootstrap? That will tell you how table effects are set up.

I imagine you'll need to dynamically insert CSS rules with how you build the table, e.g., use `<table>` instead of `<div>`.

Comment: yes but look here: http://jsbin.com/EXeGebE/1/edit nothing happend becouse first load google css instead twitter bootstrap css ...

Comment: It looks like the `jsapi` script is overriding everything. The `.google-visualization-table-table` class is being applied overriding the Bootstrap classes. If you inspect the DOM you'll see that when you add `class="table"` to `<table id='table_div'>`, the Bootstrap classes are overridden because the Google Charts classes are being added further within the table. Can you override that?

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205446/how-to-prevent-loading-google-charts-table-css

I hope it works for you.